# Random element between -x and x in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, random

Hi I would like to generate a random number between -x and x in JavaScript.
This is what I have :

```js
function randomInt(nb){
let absoluteVal = Math.ceil(Math.random()*nb)
let sign = Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
return sign == 1 ? absoluteVal*(-1) : absoluteVal;
}
console.log(randomInt(4))
```

It works but it is rather inelegant.
I was wondering if somebody knew a better solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example with `n = 4`, it generates this values:

```
-4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4
```

In total `9` elements. By using positive values, it generates `0` ... `8` with an offset of `-4`.

```js
function randomInt(n) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 * n + 1)) - n;
}

console.log(randomInt(4));
console.log(randomInt(4));
console.log(randomInt(4));
console.log(randomInt(4));
console.log(randomInt(4));
console.log(randomInt(4));
console.log(randomInt(4));
console.log(randomInt(4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Math.random()` (returns a random number between 0 and 1) allows you to do it ( using `Math.ceil()` is used to rounds a number up to the next largest integer)

```js
function randomInt(nb){
   return Math.ceil(Math.random() * nb) * (Math.round(Math.random()) ? 1 : -1)
}

console.log(randomInt(4));
console.log(randomInt(4));
console.log(randomInt(4));
console.log(randomInt(4));
console.log(randomInt(4));
```

More about `Math.ceil()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil

More about `Math.random()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random